# Deleting opposite duplicates in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have some issues that I hope you can lend a helping hand towards.
So I have some data with opposite value, for example:

---

```
Amount  Type    ID  
 10000  10      25  
-10000  10      25  
 20000  11      30  
 30000  12      49  
-30000  12      49
```

Sorry for the ugly table.

But how can I delete the lines where the amount cancelled out? I would like the ones with 10000 and -10000 to be deleted. But I wont know the specific type and id number. (30000 and -30000 is the same issue).

Any ideas? I've been searching forever, but can only find how to remove a duplicate row, and not both rows.

Hope it makes sense :)

---

Update. Thanks for the solutions so far! :) 
There *can* be more than 1:1 in the amount column, but those wouldn't identical Type and ID. For exampel could a 6th entry look like this:

```
Amount  Type    ID  
 10000  10      25  
-10000  10      25  
 20000  11      30  
 30000  12      49  
-30000  12      49
 10000  31      42
```

And the last one should not be deleted :) Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: And what's your primary key?

Comment: If there are three rows with 10000 and one with -10000, which of the three rows with 10000 should be deleted? Also, if you have a row with 10000 and another with 20000, and one with -30000, do you want those three deleted as well?

Comment: Racle will the types of the same amount will be the same ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your update. Could there be more than 2 rows with the same type/id as long as they're not duplicates?

Comment: The 'reverse duplicates' I would like to remove will have a directly opposite amount and the same type and id. Other id and/or types can have the same amount, but it cannot have different amount and same id (in that case it would not need to be removed).

Answer (score 1):

On the basis only of the limited information provided...

```
DELETE x 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.type = x.type 
   AND y.amount = x.amount * -1;
```